# Can you send mp3 record found on a website straight to a podcast app such as "Podcast Player"?

Tags: google-chrome, audio, android, mp3, podcasts

I have recently found a great tool on Product Hunt called [Send as a Podcast](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/send-as-podcast/fblchjbbkkaoobkhhbloehgkpdlomido?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) it's a chrome extension that allows you to select a text found on any website and then send it straight to your preferred podcast player app where you can listen to it! This got me thinking, is there a way to send an mp3 record that found on a website straight to a podcast player where I can listen to it in the app instead of the browser?
Thank you in advance! ♥

Comment: This depends entirely on the podcast player you want to use. Do you have any specific application in mind?

Comment: I use "Podcast player" but any podcast player would be fine for me as long as this thing works on it! 